# How to make a TemplateField read-only until the edit button is pressed?

Tags: asp.net

I have a `GridView` with various fields, one of which I have used `TemplateFields` for in order to have a datepicker in it. I've set the `GridView` to be editable and for all the other fields, this works great and they stay locked until the `edit` button is pressed.

Unfortunately, the `TemplateField` stays editable at all times. I want them to stay readonly until 'Edit' is clicked.

Some code to illustrate what I'm doing.

default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" 
CssClass="gvdatatablem, table table-striped table-bordered" 
DataKeyNames="fmatter" PageSize="25">

<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Letter Sent">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="udtltrsent" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" Class='datepicker' ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="uheld" HeaderText="Held" 
    SortExpression="uheld" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="udtresponse" HeaderText="Response" 
    SortExpression="udtresponse" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="clname1" HeaderText="clname1" 
    SortExpression="clname1" readonly="true" />
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Javascript at the bottom to implement [Datatables](https://datatables.net) and Bootstrap datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Also the GridView1_PreRender method is just to change the table format, for Datatables to work

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Replace the <td> with <th> and adds the scope attribute
                GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

                //Adds the <thead> and <tbody> elements required for DataTables to work
                GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

                //Adds the <tfoot> element required for DataTables to work
                //GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
            }
```

Comment: And where is the edit button?

Comment: I've added it to the GridView with: AutoGenerateEditButton="True"

Comment: Oh, I see. You should be able to use `EditTemplate` for that without any issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution worked for me is Use label in ItemTemplate and Keep EditItemTemplate for Textboxes. After Edit get that textbox date to label text.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Letter Sent">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="udtltrsent" runat="server"  Class='datepicker' ></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>    
</Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. Except now the data doesn't update into the database!